# Как передать String из Java в JS?

Tags: javascript, java, android

Я использую библиотеку [JsBridge](https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge) для передачи данных из android activity в webview с js.

Я отправляю string через метод

```
webView.send("Привет");
```

В консоли я вижу следующее

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "{"data":"Привет"}", source: 
>   file:///android_asset/demo.html (1)

Каким образом можно получить "Привет" из data в demo.html как текстовый ресурс?

Answer (score 2):

Дык в по приведенной вами же ссылке же черным по белому код:

```
WebViewJavascriptBridge.callHandler(
    'submitFromWeb'
    , {'param': str1}
    , function(responseData) {
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "send get responseData from java, data = " + responseData
    }
);
```

что вас в нем не устраивает?